# jQuery: Close a button, remember that action in cache

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a solution for the following mechanism:

I have a bottom player that is being displayed on all pages with a "x" close button in a corner. Whenever I click "X" the player would close, but if I refresh the page it's shown again and I need to click "X" again to hide it.

Can I store that information (e.g. that I already clicked on "X") and store it in cache? How?

A working jsFiddle of the player: http://jsfiddle.net/Gj2Rx/

Comment: I'm interesting in knowing more about this "bottom player"

Comment: This looks like a job for Cookies!

Comment: What do you think about local storage? If you have a player in javascript...is it HTML5? http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/

Comment: @Madbreaks: I didn't view it as that when I wrote it, but it's funny now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a cookie.  [Here's a decent guide](http://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_cookies.php).

Cheers

Comment: Wow @rocket, that was the fastest edit ever!  I tried to edit it myself but you'd beat me.  Thanks.  :)

Comment: Yep, I'm a ninja, don't tell anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use a cookie and then check the cookie before you display the player.